# Rails send event when editing record aswell as create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, edit

I have the following code in my controller:

```
  # GET /kases/1/edit
  def edit 
    @kase = Kase.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => 'kaseshow'} # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @kase }
      format.pdf { render :layout => false }
    end 
  end

  # POST /kases
  # POST /kases.xml
  def create
    @company = Company.find(params[:kase][:company_id])
    @kase = @company.kases.new(params[:kase])

    if @kase.save
        UserMailer.deliver_makeakase("xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com", "Highrise", @kase) if params[:sendtohighrise]
        UserMailer.deliver_makeakaseteam("xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.co.uk", "Highrise", @kase) if params[:notify_team_of_creation]
        @kase.create_freeagent_project(current_user) if params[:send_to_freeagent]

        redirect_to(@kase)

        #flash[:notice] = 'Case was successfully created.'
        flash[:notice] = fading_flash_message("Case was successfully created.", 5)
      else
        render :new
      end        
  end
```

I am trying to make it so if the user edits a case and then selects the Send to Freeagent tickbox:

```
@kase.create_freeagent_project(current_user) if params[:send_to_freeagent]
```

then the case is resent to Freeagent (online accounting software). I'm not worried about dealing with duplicates because if the case already exists in Freeagent then the user won't need to resend it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your 'update' method?  The edit is only called when you are loading the data and rendering the page the user will see to edit the record.  When save/update/submit is clicked on that page, it should be calling the 'update' method in the controller. So, you should be able to put that same line into the 'update' method in the true condition of the if block that looks something like this:

```
if @kase.update_attributes(params[:kase])
    #your code would go here
    @kase.create_freeagent_project(current_user) if params[:send_to_freeagent]
    #the rest of the code would go here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is, you could create checkbox/radio/hidden field in your edit form.

If you want to create some models for the Kase, you could as well look at accepts_nested_attributes